# How to do Unit Testing for the C++ service which performs IPC communication using Unix domain socket in linux?

Tags: c++, linux, googletest, googlemock

I am developing an C++ service to achieve IPC using Unix domain socket in Linux.

How can I perform Unit Testing to test **CreateSocket and RunServer class method** all use case?

Can someone suggest a way to perform Unit Testing for such kind of IPC communication service ? I am new to Unit Testing.
I am not sure how to design class such a way that I can perform Unit Testing.

Need to Test following Functionality for Unit Testing:

1. CreateSocket - success
2. CreateSocket - Failed at  unlink system call
3. CreateSocket - Failed at  socket system call
4. CreateSocket - Failed at  bind system call
5. CreateSocket - Failed at  listen system call
6. RunServer -  Success
7. RunServer -  Failed at accept system call
8. RunServer -  Failed at read system call
9. RunServer -  Failed at write system call
10. RunServer -  Failed at default switch case error case

```
#include <sys/types.h>
#include <sys/socket.h>
#include <sys/un.h>
#include <stdio.h>
#include <string.h>
#include <stdlib.h>
#include <errno.h>
#include <unistd.h>
#include <sys/select.h>
#include <sys/stat.h>

#define SERVER_SOCKET       "/dev/ipcserver"

#define TOTAL_QUEUE_CONNECTION  10

enum message_type
{
    REQUEST,
    RESPONSE,
    DICONNECT
};

struct message 
{
    message_type type;
    char data [50];
};

class Server
{
    private:
    int server_socket_fd;
    fd_set fds, readfds;
    int fdmax;


    struct message message;

    public:
    int CreateSocket(void);
    int RunServer();

    Server()
    {
        FD_ZERO (&fds);
        FD_ZERO (&readfds);
    }

    ~Server()
    {

    }
};


int Server::CreateSocket()
{
    // create a unix domain socket, 
    struct stat statbuf;
    if (stat (SERVER_SOCKET, &statbuf) == 0) 
    {
        if (unlink (SERVER_SOCKET) == -1)
        {
            printf ("unlink failed \n");
            return -1;
        }   
    }

    if ((server_socket_fd = socket (AF_UNIX, SOCK_SEQPACKET, 0)) == -1)
    {
        printf ("socket failed \n ");
        return -1;
    }

    struct sockaddr_un socket_address;

    memset (&socket_address, 0, sizeof (struct sockaddr_un));
    socket_address.sun_family = AF_UNIX;
    strncpy (socket_address.sun_path, SERVER_SOCKET, sizeof(socket_address.sun_path) - 1);

    if (bind (server_socket_fd, (const struct sockaddr *) &socket_address, sizeof (struct sockaddr_un)) == -1)
    {
        printf ("bind failed \n");
        return -1;
    }    

    if (listen (server_socket_fd, TOTAL_QUEUE_CONNECTION) == -1)
    {
        printf ("listen failed \n");
        return -1;
    }    
    
    FD_SET (server_socket_fd, &fds);
    fdmax = server_socket_fd;

    return 0;
}


int Server::RunServer()
{
    while (1) 
    {
        readfds = fds;
        // monitor readfds for readiness for reading
        if (select (fdmax + 1, &readfds, NULL, NULL, NULL) == -1)
        {
            printf ("select failed \n");
            return -1;
        }
        // Some sockets are ready. Examine readfds
        for (int fd = 0; fd < (fdmax + 1); fd++) 
        {
            if (FD_ISSET (fd, &readfds)) 
            {  // fd is ready for reading
                if (fd == server_socket_fd) 
                {  // request for new connection
                    int fd_new;
                    if ((fd_new = accept (server_socket_fd, NULL, NULL)) == -1)
                    {
                        printf ("accept failed \n");

                    }
                    FD_SET (fd_new, &fds);
                    if (fd_new > fdmax)
                    {
                        fdmax = fd_new;
                    }
                }
                else  // data from an existing connection
                {
                    memset (&message, '\0', sizeof (struct message));
                    ssize_t numbytes = read (fd, &message, sizeof (struct message));

                    if (numbytes == -1)
                    {
                        printf ("read failed \n");
                    }
                    else
                    {
                        printf ("Data received from client : \n");
                        switch (message.type) 
                        {
                            case REQUEST:
                            {
                                memset (&message, '\0', sizeof (struct message));
                                char data[] = {0x01,0x02,0x03,0x04,0x05,0x06};
                                memcpy(message.data,data,sizeof(data));
                                message.type = RESPONSE;
                                if (write (fd, &message, sizeof (struct message)) == -1)
                                {
                                    printf ("write error \n");
                                }
                                break;
                            }
                            case DICONNECT:  // clear client connection from monitored fd set
                            {
                                FD_CLR(fd,&fds);
                            }
                            default:
                            {
                                printf ("Unexpected message from client\n");
                                break;
                            }
                        }
                    }
                }
            } // if 
        } // for
    } // while (1)
    return 0;
}


int main()
{
    Server IPCServer;
    int status = IPCServer.CreateSocket();
    if(status == 0)
    {
        IPCServer.RunServer();
    }
    else
    {
        printf("IPCServer create fail\n");
        return -1;
    }
    return 0;
}
```

Comment: Start by listing everything you want to test?

Comment: I updated test cases which I need to perform @Shawn